# How to supply puppeteer with a SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, proxy, puppeteer, cacerts

I am using the luminati / Brightdata proxy manager and have puppeteer connected to it locally. All of this exists within a docker-compose network that I created for local dev.

The problem I have occurs when I turn on SSL analyzing and I get the `net::ERR_CERT_INVALID` error from puppeteer.

Is there a way for me to just supply the .crt file to the puppeteer browser on launch so it trusts the certificate? The luminati cert can be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luminati-io/luminati-proxy/master/bin/ca.crt.

I have tried supplying the chromium --ignore-certificate-errors flag, and this works on the proxy managers' end, but it does not work for logging into my target site.

Comment: I found out that the answer for this depends on what docker image you are running puppeteer on (for me, linux/debian). I tried running `update-ca-certificates`. Note this will update the CA certificate for some operations (curl), but this is not where puppeteer looks for CA certificates. What ended up working for me was using `certutil`. My example dockerfile cmds:
`RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.pki/nssdb`
`RUN certutil -d $HOME/.pki/nssdb -N`
`RUN certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -n luminati -A -t "TCu,Cu,Tu" -i` `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/luminati.crt`